# returning latest file in directory for specific format

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory with files of the format:

```
test_report-01-13-2014.11_53-en.zip
test_report-12-04-2013.11_53-en.zip
```

and I need to return the last files based on the date in the file names not the date the file was last touched. If I do that I could end up with the 2013 file instead, which would be wrong .
I am doing the following, but it's not working.
I am passing in the following paramaters:

```
mypath = "C:\\temp\\test\\"
mypattern = "test_report-%m-%d-%Y*"
myfile = getLatestFile(mypath, mypattern)

def getLatestFile(path="./", pattern="*"):
   fformat= path + pattern
   archives = glob.glob(fformat)

   if len(archives) > 0:
       return archives[-1]
   else:
       return None
```

any idea what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you have control over the naming convention of the files? Answers below will work, but a better naming might make for better readability both from python and when listing files elsewhere.

Comment: unfortunately not. I am stuck with the format.

Comment: Fair enough; always worth a shot! The below answers should work then

Answer (score 2):

`glob` returns matching *paths* in an arbitrary order, and it doesn't understand `%m-%d-%Y` (its not that smart).

You need to read the list of paths, extract the file name, then get the date from the file name. This will be the key that you will use to sort the list of files.

Here is one way to do just that:

```
import glob
import os
import datetime

def sorter(path):
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[12:22], '%m-%d-%Y')

pattern = "test_report-*"
search_path = r'C:\temp\test\' # or 'c:/temp/test/'

file_list = glob.glob(pattern+search_path)

# Order by the date
ordered_list = sorted(file_list, key=sorter, reverse=True)
```

[`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) is a function to return the last component of a path; since `glob` will return the full path, the last component will be the file name.

As your file name has a fixed format - instead of mucking with regular expressions I just grabbed the date part by slicing the file name, and converted it to a datetime object.

Finally, `sorted` *returns* the result of the sort (the normal `sort` method is an *in place* sort). The key function is what extract the date and returns it, `reverse=True` is required to get the returned list in the order of latest first.

You can shorten the code a bit by passing the result of `glob.glob` directly to sorted:

`ordered_list = sorted(glob.glob(pattern+search_path), key=sorter, reverse=True)`

To combine this with the function you have written:

```
import glob, os, datetime

def sorter(path):
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[12:22], '%m-%d-%Y')

def getLatestFile(path="./", pattern="*"):
   fformat = path + pattern
   archives = glob.glob(fformat)

   if len(archives):
      return sorted(archives, key=sorter, reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: Note that `max(archives, key=sorted)` could be used here to save the `sorted`

Answer (score 1):

The order of archives is arbitrary, but not only that your filenames can't be sorted alphabetically (month comes before year). Easiest way is to `sort` your list with a `key` function that extracts a `datetime` object from the filename:

```
import datetime

def getDateFromFilename(filename):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp[12:-7], '%m-%d-%Y.%H_%M')
    except ValueError:
        return -1

archives.sort(key=getDateFromFilename)
```

Comment: this works, but I need to also do this for test1_report test2_report etc.... 
key functions only take one parameter. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/glob.html) [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> `os.listdir(path='.')`
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

So you must either use a stricter filter or order the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sort your list by name, just do `sorted(archives = glob.glob(fformat))`

Comment: OP is trying to sort by the date in the filename, not just by name. Also your second option will store None in archives because .sort() doesn't return anything

Comment: Ah, sorry. I normally write dates YYYY-MM-DD. Then soting by name is sufficient. I read too fast...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the input. I used a little bit of everything and ended up with this, which works fine for my purposes.

```
def getDateFromFilename(filename):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, myPattern + '%m-%d-%Y.%H_%M-en.zip')
    except ValueError:
        return -1

def getLatestFile(path, pattern):
    files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(myPath) if f.startswith(pattern)])
    files.sort(key=getDateFromFilename)

    if len(files) > 0:
        return files[-1]
    else:
        return  None
```

Comment: if myPattern were to change, how can I pass in new patterns?
Can I pass in parameters here:
files.sort(key=getDateFromFilename(filename, pattern))