# get latest file based on filename python

Tags: python, date, datetime

starting a new thread from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131775/returning-latest-file-in-directory-for-specific-format?noredirect=1#comment31837797_21131775)

I have a directory with files in this format:

```
Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Another Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Holiday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Weekday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Special-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip

Report_Test-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip
Another Report_Test-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip
Report_Holiday-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip
Report_Weekday-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip
Report_Special-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip
```

I have no control over the file naming and the file name pattern stays consistent.
I've tried everything in the previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131775/returning-latest-file-in-directory-for-specific-format?noredirect=1#comment31837797_21131775)

I need to be able to return the last file and the last two files based on date in filename.
Unfortunately %m-%d-%Y format of the date is throwing me off. I end up with 2013 files because 12 in 12-16-2013 is higher than 01 in 01-16-2014.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate **throwing me off**?

Comment: I think it is better to edit the title to represent your problem. something like "comparing dates in python"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Extract date string from the filenames.
- convert it to `date` object.
- find last date. (1)
- filter filename using the last date.

---

```
filenames = [
    'Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip',
    'Another Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip',
    'Report_Holiday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip',
    'Report_Weekday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip',
    'Report_Special-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip',
    'Report_Test-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip',
    'Another Report_Test-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip',
    'Report_Holiday-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip',
    'Report_Weekday-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip',
    'Report_Special-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip',
] # Used in place of `os.listdir(....)`

import re
import datetime

date_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\b')
def get_date(filename):
    matched = date_pattern.search(filename)
    if not matched:
        return None
    m, d, y = map(int, matched.groups())
    return datetime.date(y, m, d)

dates = (get_date(fn) for fn in filenames)
dates = (d for d in dates if d is not None)
last_date = max(dates)
last_date = last_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
filenames = [fn for fn in filenames if last_date in fn]
for fn in filenames:
    print(fn)
```

output:

```
Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Another Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Holiday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Weekday-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
Report_Special-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot. but what alternatives do I have instead of max() ? If I let's say would have to find the last two instead of only the last, or if I wanted to find the second to last?

Comment: @Eric, Use `sorted` or `list.sort` for such cases. (Before doing that, you need to remove duplicated dates.., preferably using `set`).

Comment: meaning, changes the 'dates' from a generator to a list and sort it?

Comment: @Eric, `dates = sorted(set(dates)); last_two_dates = dates[-2:]`

Comment: @Eric, I mean: There's multiple sames dates in the generator. You can use `set` data structures to get unique dates.

Comment: right, but in that case dates, should be a list, not a generator right? so instead of 
dates = (d for d in dates if d is not None)
I would use:
dates = [d for d in dates if d is not None]
?

Comment: @Eric, No it does not needed to be a list. `set`, `sorted` both accept any iterable. (Not only sequence types like list, tuple, strings, but generators are also iterable)

Answer (score 0):

use `.split("-")` function for it.
like

```
x="Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip"
y=x.split("-") #['Report_Test', '01', '16', '2014.09_42', 'en.zip']
```

then make some sort and get the latest

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own compare function to compare according to your logic

```
filenames = ["Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip",
             "Report_Special-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip"]

def compare_dates(fn1,fn2):
        # parse the date information
        day1,month1,year1 = fn1.split(".")[0].split("-")[-3:]
        day2,month2,year2 = fn2.split(".")[0].split("-")[-3:]
        ret = cmp(year1,year2) # first compare the years
        if ret != 0:
            return ret
        ret = cmp(month1,month2) # if years equal, compare months
        if ret != 0:
            return ret
        return cmp(day1,day2) # if months equal, compare days

filenames.sort(cmp=compare_dates)
```

and now 2013 is before 2014:

```
>>> filenames
['Report_Special-12-16-2013.10_52-en.zip', 'Report_Test-01-16-2014.09_42-en.zip
```

Comment: Use of `cmp` argument should be avoided in flavor of `key` argument. `cmp` involves more comparisons (in general slower). And it's gone in Python 3.x.

Comment: I must admit i didn't understand your comment. what do you mean "flavor of key" and "involves more comparisons"?

Comment: See [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). (I give you the link of `sorted` function instead of `list.sort` because there's no direct link to the `list.sort` method in the documentation, but they have similar parameters)